# Get the path of a file using locate command, but not working for some files

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, locate, updatedb

Trying to get the path of a file using locate command, but not working for some files

`[mohan@host ~]$ locate t`

`t` is a name of the file. It is searching over `/usr` and `/var`,
but some other files in the home directory are being located with this command.

I tried doing sudo updatedb as well.
contents of /etc/updatedb.conf

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS = "yes"
PRUNEFS = "9p afs anon_inodefs auto autofs bdev binfmt_misc cgroup cifs coda configfs cpuset debugfs devpts ecryptfs exofs fuse fuse.sshfs fusectl gfs gfs2 gpfs hugetlbfs inotifyfs iso9660 jffs2 lustre mqueue ncpfs nfs nfs4 nfsd pipefs proc ramfs rootfs rpc_pipefs securityfs selinuxfs sfs sockfs sysfs tmpfs ubifs udf usbfs ceph fuse.ceph"
PRUNENAMES = ".git .hg .svn .bzr .arch-ids {arch} CVS"
PRUNEPATHS = "/afs /media /mnt /net /sfs /tmp /udev /var/cache/ccache /var/lib/yum/yumdb /var/lib/dnf/yumdb /var/spool/cups /var/spool/squid /var/tmp /var/lib/ceph"
```

[mohan@host ~]$ ls
ansible-demos-excersises  Desktop    Downloads  file2  file4  he     major  Pictures  t          test-project  Videos
desktop                   Documents  file1      file3  file5  inven  Music  Public    Templates  trash-cli     y
[mohan@host ~]$ locate file1
/home/mohan/file1
[mohan@host ~]$ locate file2
/home/mohan/file2
[mohan@host ~]$ file file1
file1: empty
[mohan@host ~]$ file file2
file2: empty
[mohan@host ~]$ file t
t: ASCII text
[mohan@host ~]$ file he
he: ASCII text
the above t and he are the files im unable to locate using locate command ,but not i checked those file types using file so i got to know i created something called ascii text can't we locate these files?

Comment: What is your question? Please add information in the question body and not (only) in the title. And please tell us where you think `t` should be found.

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/updatedb.conf` to see if the file you're looking for isn't in a path that is in the `PRUNEPATHS` or `PRUNFS` variables?

Comment: Your question is rather incomprehensible. Try to clarify what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ray yes i checked

Comment: I agree with @ArturMeinild.  Your question is unclear.  What is it that you want it to do?  "not working for some files" is a very vague question.  Is there a file `t` somewhere that you can't find?  Or is there a file `t` that is being found, but you don't think it should be?  Please give a precise example, or else no one can help you...

Comment: @pLumo i want the path of the file 't' when i use locate command

Comment: @Artur Meinild my problem is that when i use locate command to locate a file/directory for some files/directories it giving the output for correct path but for some files the locate command is not working even those files are also present in the home directory of the user. Even it seems wierd for me as well why a command is working with some files and not with others?

Comment: @AnnaMohan can we assume that you're not actually searching for `t`, since that would implicitly match any of 1000s of files with `t` anywhere in their names? If so, please give us *actual, testable examples* of files that do work and files that don't - along with their absolute pathnames.

Comment: @steeldriver once check the question again i have added some more info into the question

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file is recently created and you need to manually update the `locate`'s command database. You could do that by the command:

```
sudo updatedb
```

This command will update the database file `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`. Usually Ubuntu updates that file automatically few times in a day.